# Android: Pass selection to Parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I optimizing an application for use with the trackball. I have a ListView with rows that contain three buttons. Here is my problem: whenever I move the trackball to the child buttons of the row, the focus disappears from the parent container (the row). I want to keep the focus on the entire row, as well as whatever button is currently selected for the given row.

Basically, what I need is an attribute opposite to android:duplicateParentState, something called "android:duplicateChildState." Unfortunately, android:duplicateChildState does not exist.

At the moment I have hacked it in a way such that I set an onFocusChangedListener and force the parent container to also be selected with the ListView.setSelected method. This works, but unfortunately there is a flicker as this setSelected message is posted and run to the UI thread.

Does anybody know of a way that I can keep this focus on the parent, as I traverse the children widgets?

Comment: I may be way off here, but you say "I want to keep the focus on the entire row, as well as whatever button is currently selected for the given row." -- Meaning your want two objects to have focus which I would think is impossible.

Comment: Well, it currently works as is. So the setSelected is being set for the row such that the StateList Drawable is in the selected stay, and has an orange highlight around the entire row. Also, the button stays selected. I think the problem with my focus change listener, is that every time the trackball is moved the Android OS reassesses the state of the row and marks it as unselected, until the listener has a chance to hack and reselect.